# Executing PMML workflow in a batch mode in KNIME

Tags: knime

I'm evaluating KNIME and its PMML support. Recent attempt to execute a workflow, exported in *PMML format*, resulted in the following error: **"Workflow is locked by another Knime instance"**.

Please note that I'm executing workflows, using *KNIME Analytics Platform* (not KNIME Server) in a *batch mode*. I have read the following **related questions**, but they seem not to be PMML-focused:

- [Issue when running a workflow in Batch Mode in Windows 7](https://tech.knime.org/forum/knime-users/issue-when-running-a-workflow-in-batch-mode-in-windows-7);
- [How to remove LOCK? All batch processes suddenly "locked by another KNIME instance"](https://tech.knime.org/forum/knime-general/how-to-remove-lock-all-batch-processes-suddenly-locked-by-another-knime-instance);
- [Batch execution](https://tech.knime.org/forum/knime-general/batch-execution);
- [Disable KNIME locking of workflows in batch mode?](https://tech.knime.org/forum/knime-general/disable-knime-locking-of-workflows-in-batch-mode).

In order to execute workflows in *batch mode*, I'm using method, described in [this blog post](http://www.dataminingreporting.com/blog/run-a-knime-workflow-in-batch-mode) (I have also tried `-workflowFile=` instead of `-workflowDir=`).

P.S. A colleague of mine submitted a [similar question to KNIME forum](https://tech.knime.org/forum/knime-general/running-a-pmml-file-in-batch-mode), but due to lack of activity there and need to figure this out as soon as possible, I'm soliciting help from people on this site.

P.P.S. A couple of clarifications: 1) no (user-initiated) concurrent KNIME sessions were running in the above-mentioned scenario; 2) no lock files were present in current (workflow) directory.

Comment: Could you clarify how did you try? You cannot export a workflow in PMML format, only a model (you can export your workflow in zip format). You cannot execute a PMML model using KNIME, you need to create a workflow for that (to read the input data, the model and feed them to a predictor).

Comment: @GáborBakos: Based on examples, found across multiple sources. For example, I used the following sources: [this page (main source)](https://www.knime.org/blog/pmml-integration-in-knime), [this blog post](https://support.zementis.com/entries/21183653-exporting-pmml-pre-processing-and-model-from-knime), [this paper](https://tech.knime.org/files/knime_pmml_kdd2011.pdf), [this set of slides](https://kdd11pmml.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/pres4_berthold_kdd2011_pmml-workshop2.pdf) (slides 25-27) and [this paper](http://kdd.org/exploration_files/p5V11n1.pdf). (to be continued)

Comment: @GáborBakos: (cont'd) Now, thanks to your comment (+1), I understand that I was confused by some related materials (i.e., [this document](http://files.meetup.com/11584642/Modular%20PMML.pdf)), in particular by the term _modular PMML_, which I thought refers to a combination of analytical model, pre-processing and the rest of a whole workflow. I greatly appreciate your help. Please feel free to expand your comment into a more comprehensive answer and I will be happy to upvote and potentially accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot execute with KNIME in batch mode or otherwise PMML models, only workflows. So you need four nodes to make this work:

- a [PMML Reader](http://www.knime.org/files/node-documentation/org.knime.base.node.io.pmml.read.PMMLReaderNodeFactory.html),
- something that can read your input data (ex. [CSV Reader](http://www.knime.org/files/node-documentation/org.knime.base.node.io.csvreader.CSVReaderNodeFactory.html)),
- a predictor*: ex.

  - [JPMML Classifier](http://www.knime.org/files/node-documentation/org.knime.jpmml.classification.JPMMLClassifierNodeFactory.html),
  - [JPMML Cluster Assigner](http://www.knime.org/files/node-documentation/org.knime.jpmml.cluster.JPMMLClusterAssignerNodeFactory.html), or
  - [JPMML Regression Predictor](http://www.knime.org/files/node-documentation/org.knime.jpmml.predict.JPMMLPredictorNodeFactory.html),
- and you most probably also want to write the results (ex. with the [CSV Writer](http://www.knime.org/files/node-documentation/org.knime.base.node.io.csvwriter.CSVWriterNodeFactory.html) node).

Configure and save them as a workflow and you should execute that workflow instead of the PMML model. It should look like this:

```
|CSV Reader|----|                 |
                |JPMML Classifier |----->|CSV Writer|
|PMML Reader|---|                 |
```

(You can create a more complex workflow if you need to, this is just a basic example.)

Now you should be able to execute the workflow in batch mode as described by the blog posts you mentioned. With flow variables you can also adjust the execution runtime. (With the KNIME Server and the QuickForm nodes you have even nicer user interface.)

Please be sure you use the classifier/predictor/cluster assigner that matches your PMML model. Also note that these nodes are supposed to work with KNIME generated PMML models, there might be cornercases when they cannot be used with models generated by other tools (especially if those tools used extensions in the models).

*: though these mentioned require the KNIME labs extension for JPMML, but you can use the model specific regular KNIME nodes too if you know more about the model

Comment: Thank you very much for all your attention and help. Your answer helped me to get a better understanding of the topic (+1). However, please see my reply to Michael's comment on KNIME forum's corresponding question: https://tech.knime.org/forum/knime-general/running-a-pmml-file-in-batch-mode#comment-41820. I hope that you will have additional feedback on my points.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh I have just reacted your questions there. I hope you do not mind that I tried to explain things with concepts from R (you are probably more familiar to R than me, but I know the basics too).

Comment: Gabor, thank you. Please see my detailed comment on the forum.

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer on the KNIME Forum about that:

https://tech.knime.org/forum/knime-general/running-a-pmml-file-in-batch-mode

The workspace (not workflow!) is probably locked because he has the GUI still open when he is trying to run batch mode.

What do you mean exactly with exporting a workflow in PMML? I hope it is a model that you export in PMML.

-- Rosaria

Comment: Thank you very much for your help (+1). For more details and clarifications, please see my reply to Michael's comment on KNIME forum's corresponding question: https://tech.knime.org/forum/knime-general/running-a-pmml-file-in-batch-mode#comment-41820.